# mysqli bind_param fails but why? 

Tags: php, binding, mysqli

The following error triggers a mysql error, this is due to query not binding the parameter to the statement. I do not understand why this is happening.

This is the error returned by the else clause:

```
ERROR -> 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
use near '? ORDER BY dateCreated DESC' at line 4`
```

Here is the code in question:

```
$userId = 1;
if ($stmt = $link->query("
    SELECT o.id, dateCreated, firstValue
    FROM user_orders o 
    LEFT JOIN order_delivery d ON o.id = d.id 
    WHERE o.userId = ? 
    ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $userId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
else
{
    $pageContent = '
        <p>ERROR -> '.$link->errno.' : '.$link->error.'</p>
    ';

}
```

Could someone possibly point our where i have gone wrong with this and why this mysql error is occuring.

Thank you for taking the time to read through this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`mysqli::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), not `query` to prepare your prepared statement.

`query` will try to run that query which isn't valid until the parameters have been bound.